# Can I charge my laptop with this charger

Tags: laptop, battery, adapter, charger

I forgot my charger at home but really need to get my pc running. I have a charger from a friend of my my pc has an output of 19V / 7.1 A and the friends has 19V/ 4.3 A. I know that the charger might overheat but what if I only charge when my pc is turned of will it still draw as many electricity when it is turned off? And I have a bit of a problem finding the polarity of my pc I found the one on the charger though

Edit: Found another one 19,5 V and 6,7 A should that one work

Comment: If you use your friends charger you will damage his charger.  Your laptop will draw more amperage then the charger can support.  At least if I am reading the information you have provided correctly.  In any case I personally wouldn't want to use it due to the huge difference in amperage.

Comment: I found another one the new charger here has 19,5 V and 6,7 A this one is pretty close I am only worried about the higher volts cause it usually should be equal any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure on how you've worded the question. If the amperage the machine ***requires*** is higher than the power supply can provide (In this case, if the PSU provides 4.2A and your laptop requires 7.1A), this is a problem and you **should not use it**. Your laptop may attempt to draw more power than the power supply can provide, and cause damage to the unit. If, however, you mean the power supply can provide a greater amperage than your machine needs (EG. your machine requires 4.3 A and the PSU provides 7.1 A), this is fine to use.

Do not attempt to power up your machine with it until you are sure of the polarity *and* the PSU is able to provide sufficient amperage, as if it's incorrect it *could* damage the power supply, the machine, or both.

Comment: what about 6,7 A and 19,5 V the  amperage is almost the same the voltage is higher by 0,5 V could there be problems?

Comment: There is a huge difference between 6.7 A and 7.1 A,, put it this way, 0.5 A can cause serious problems to the human body.

Comment: @TenebrisNocte Amperage equal to or greater than is okay. Voltage should be equal. Any other scenario carries a high risk of damaging something. *Maybe* it could work for a period, but is it worth the chance of damage? I'd say not.

Answer (score 0):

The power supply on your notebook is a switched mode power supply. SMPS's powered of the power grid will always employ a transformer to archieve galvanic isolation. This has the sideeffect of limiting the amount of current that can flow (think of it like this: You can not blow out a fuse in your home by shorting the output of a PSU, because you are only shorting the secondary winding of a trafo). Therefore you won't burn anything. Unless you reverse the polarity, in which case you *still* won't burn anything, as the charging electronics on your nb's mobo will check for that.

The worst that can happen is that your nb won't charge.